# Enter Ether to send

Tags: web3js, metamask

Very new to EJS and trying to figure this out.
Posting here after trying for few hours. I am able to send an amount of ETH to a contract but don't have an option to choose how much.

Trying to find a way to be able to enter the amount of eth to be sent before sending using Metamask.

Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>USE MetaMask</title>



  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>MetaMask</h1>
    <a href="https://github.com/MetaMask/TipButton">View on Github</a>
    <div class="tip-button"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
  </body>

<script>
var MY_ADDRESS = '0x82462c60EC0e82AF991B93E82D3B1Ab5f20D30F4'
var tipButton = document.querySelector('.tip-button')
tipButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (typeof web3 === 'undefined') {
    return renderMessage('<div>You need to install <a href=“https://metmask.io“>MetaMask </a> to use this feature.  <a href=“https://metmask.io“>https://metamask.io</a></div>')
  }
  var user_address = web3.eth.accounts[0]
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to: MY_ADDRESS,
    from: user_address,
    value: web3.toWei('1', 'ether'),
    gas: 302575,
    gasPrice: 30000000000,
  }, function (err, transactionHash) {
    if (err) return renderMessage('There was a problem!: ' + err.message)
    // If you get a transactionHash, you can assume it was sent,
    // or if you want to guarantee it was received, you can poll
    // for that transaction to be mined first.
    renderMessage('Thanks for the generosity!!')
  })
})
function renderMessage (message) {
  var messageEl = document.querySelector('.message')
  messageEl.innerHTML = message
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: the field value is the one you need to change. You can send an amout of Wei that you can calculate from other subcurrencies. `web3.toWei('1','ether')` will return the amount of one ether in Wei;

Answer (score 1):

Here in your Script you have hard coded the value to be 1.

```
value: web3.toWei('1', 'ether');
```

So it will be sending 1 ETH every time.

Take the value set it later using JavaScript.

A basic JS tutorial [like this](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/JavaScript_Introduction.html) might help you.